# Can we describe the nonabelian exterior square of a finite 2-generated metabelian group?

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite 2-generated metabelian group, and let $S$ be a schur covering group, so that we have an exact sequence
$$1\rightarrow M(G)\rightarrow S\rightarrow G\rightarrow 1$$
where $M(G)$ is the Schur multiplier of $G$, and $M(G)\le S'$ (The $'$ denotes derived subgroup). This implies that $S^{ab}= G^{ab}$, and we have an exact sequence
$$1\rightarrow M(G)\rightarrow S'\rightarrow G'\rightarrow 1$$
Thus, since $G$ is metabelian, $G'$ is abelian, so $S'$ is also a metabelian group, and is equal to the [exterior square $G\wedge G$ of $G$](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Exterior_square_of_a_group).

It seems reasonable that we should be able to say something about $(G\wedge G)^{ab},(G\wedge G)'$ in terms of $G',G^{ab}$,...etc, though I'm having some difficulty getting an intuitive understanding of what this exterior square "is", and how to work with it.

Is there a good book that discusses nonabelian exterior products of groups?

Comment: I'm afraid that there's no good textbook-format reference for nonabelian homological algebra, but works of G. Ellis and G. Donadze on the subject are pretty self-contained. On your question: if $G$ is finite metabelian and is an extension of $\pi$-group $G_{ab}$ by $\pi'$-group $G'$ of squarefree order (i. e. G' has trivial multiplier), then $G \wedge G$ = $G' \times (G_{ab} \wedge G_{ab})$. As for actual computation (in terms of presentations) of tensor square for finite solvable groups there were A. McDermott thesis, papers by N. Rocco, and some materials on G. Ellis homepage.

Comment: @DenisT. Thank you for your comment! I'm revisiting this question, and was wondering - what do you mean by a $\pi$-group (or $\pi'$-group)?

Comment: @DenisT. (And do you have a specific reference for your statement involving $\pi$-groups?)